# Magnetic acceleration for a spacecraft

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, space, propulsion

This is a naive question about a shower thought, but perhaps someone could indulge me since I don't understand the physics at a sufficient level to know why it would not work.

Could the electromagnetic acceleration and deceleration of a rotating physical masses be used as a method of propulsion for a spacecraft? Since access to chemical reaction mass for conventional or ionic propulsion is a problem in space, but using a nuclear reactor there could be plenty of energy to be spent.

I'm thinking of something like a reasonably heavy weight rotating around an axle at a convenient distance (without a counterweight), where electromagnets would accelerate it near to the point to the opposite direction where you wish to accelerate at, then the weight continues rotation and is decelerated with magnets at the opposite side, again providing acceleration to the desired direction. If two of such devices operate in sync, it would be symmetric and cancel the undesired forces to the spacecraft? Or would it vibrate so much that it would be useless?

Comment: Your proposal appears to violate conservation of momentum. Usually, when a system appears to violate conservation of momentum (or any other well-established physical law), it means that you haven't completely understood it. For example, what forces, if any, would your swinging mass exert on its axle? (Hint: the answer can't be "none," because if it exerted no force on the axle, then what would be the point of even _having_ the axle?)

Comment: This is like trying to push a bus while standing inside it. Your hands are pushing on the car walls, yes, but your feet are braced against the floor and pushing the car in the opposite direction so the car does not move. It also doesn't mean if you get a running start and jump-push because the instant you jump forward you put the bus back but the instant you hit the walls you push it forward so no net motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scheme will not work, since as Solomon Slow points out it would violate momentum conservation. You can also analyze this from the standpoint that forces come in pairs (action -> reaction) and it's easy to miss the reaction force, which cancels the "thrust" you hope to generate.  I spent almost a year trying to build exactly this sort of device 50 years ago and can attest from personal experience that it will not do what you hope it will, and that an engineering dynamics class will explain in detail why not. It worked for me...